# when use Regex in for loop PHP

Tags: php, regex, loops

I need use Regex in loop PHP And I have Problem like below.
when i write this code it's work fine :

```
$phone_number= '2222463';

for ($i=1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
  if((preg_match("/^[$i]{3}/", $phone_number))){
    return true;
   }
}
```

but below code not return true :

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
  if((preg_match("/^[$i]{$i}/", $phone_number))){
    return true;
   }
}
```

> Note : {2}=={$i}

Comment: it should atleast be true when `$i` is 3.

Comment: What is the value of `$phone_number`? Does it begin with '333'? What are you really trying to check here?

Comment: in both case it's working fine

Comment: @Bilal It's not.

Comment: @deceze right +1...

Comment: I still don't know (despite the accepted answer) what 'working' means in this context. What is the code supposed to be checking?

Comment: I check @deceze code and is work fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$i = 3;
echo "{3}", PHP_EOL, "{$i}";
// {3}
// 3
```

`{$...}` is part of the [complex PHP string interpolation syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex), and `{$i}` is interpreted as one variable interpolation. You need to escape/double the brackets here:

```
"/^[$i]{{$i}}/"
```